# Braintree drop-in not loading django

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-templates, braintree

I'm integrating `braintree` into my `django` project, and have a problem with `drop-in` payment form, it's not loading, can any one help me and see my template, I'm missing something and can not see what is wrong. I'm reading [documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/javascript/v2) on this matter and using [this](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/javascript/v2) example, it's just remade for django, here is my template, further more `tags` `charge_form` and `braintree_javascript_code` are loaded into `base.html`.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block charge_form %}


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
          <form class="" action="" method="post" id="example_form">
             {% csrf_token %} 
             <div id="dropin-container"></div>
             <input type="submit" value="Pay 300$" name="" id=""/>
          </form> 
       </div> 
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}


{% block braintree_javascript_code %}

<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/js/braintree-2.24.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var client_token = '{{ request.session.braintree_client_token }}'; 
    braintree.setup(client_token, "dropin", {
        container: "dropin-container";
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by building my self a custom form for `braintree` payment. I didn't solve why their `dropin` is not loading into my template, and didn't like [hosted fields](https://www.braintreepayments.com/blog/your-checkout-our-iframes/) approach, which is good, I just don't like don't touch, don't style or modify `i-frame` form, so I made a form out of bootstrap3 and pass the form id in `braintree.setup()`.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block braintree_charge_form %}

<div class="row">
    <p style="padding:60px"></p>
</div>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
          <form class="" action="" method="post" id="example_form">
             {% csrf_token %} 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="card-number">Card Number</label>
                <input type="" class="form-control" id="card-number" placeholder="Card Number">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="security-code-field">CVV</label>
                <input type="" class="form-control" id="security-code-field" placeholder="CVV">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="expiration-date">Expiration Date</label>
                <input type="" class="form-control" id="expiration-date" placeholder="Expiration Date">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form> 
       </div> 
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}


{% block braintree_javascript_code %}

<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/js/braintree-2.24.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var client_token = '{{ request.session.braintree_client_token }}'; 
    braintree.setup(client_token, "custom", {
        id: "example_form";
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```